# Hard code a domain into Yoast SEO canonical URLs

Tags: seo, subdomains, site-url

For various reasons, I've been asked to duplicate a wordpress blog across multiple subdomains. Obviously, this will cause duplicate content issues, which I hope to mitigate with the use of a canonical tag, pointing back to a single sub-domain (www).

I'm using Yoast SEO on the site however. This auto generates the canonical tag - and appears to use whichever sub-domain I'm on at the time.
Presumably it's picking this up from the WP_SITEURL setting or similar, but I've had to modify this to allow the multiple sub-domains in the first place.

Is there any way that I can force Yoast SEO to use a single sub-domain for all canonical URLs? I still need all links on the site and general functionality to make use of the other sub-domains - whichever it's currently on - but the canonical should always point back to a single sub-domain.

Please note: redirection is not an option.

I figure the best way to do this is with the Yoast SEO API, but I'm unfamiliar with it.
I think I need to adjust the following to include my desired sub-domain, but I'm unsure as to the syntax to get the rest of the generated URL in there.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'http://www.' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a small plugin using which you should be able to replace the domain for canonical url to another domain.

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: WPSE WPSEO Canonical
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com
 * Description: Changes canonical url domain.
 * Author: Sisir
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author URI: http://developerpage.net
 *
 **/

add_filter('wpseo_canonical', 'swpseo_canonical_domain_replace');
function swpseo_canonical_domain_replace($url){

    $domain = 'google.com'; // this can be loaded from option table if you want admin to set it.
    $parsed = parse_url(home_url());
    $current_site_domain = $parsed['host'];
    return str_replace($current_site_domain, $domain, $url);

}
```

*Note: Code Not tested. Let me know if it doesn't work.*